# how to launch a terminal with specified directory

Tags: shell

I am working in a Linux environment. I am wonder how I can achieve something like the following:

```
xterm -e "cd <directory_I_want_to_go>"
```

Looks like the command `cd` is not like `ls` which resides in `/usr/bin`. But neither

```
xterm -e "ls ~"
```

works.

Someone please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason neither of those works is that `-e` tells `xterm` to execute the specified command *and then terminate*.  If you do `xterm -e vi some-file`, you'll get a new xterm window with vi running in it; when you quit vi, the window closes.  Without `-e`, it invokes your shell and stays open until you exit the shell.  For non-interactive commands, the window will close immediately after showing the output.  You can use `xterm -hold -e "ls ~"` to keep the window open (but note that that still won't give you an interactive shell).

Comment: @Keith: ok. Thank you for pointing that out. The question now becomes: How can I do "ls ~" in the newly launched terminal and show the results there?

Comment: Did you try the `-hold` option?  Or did you want to run `ls` and then launch an interactive shell?

Comment: @Keith, yes, I tried. But I also want to have an interactive terminal besides showing the result of "ls ~"

Comment: `xterm -e 'ls ~ ; bash -l` (assuming `bash` is your login shell).

Comment: @Keith: `bash-3.00$ xterm -e 'ls ~ ; bash -l
>`. I got this kind of behavior, i.e. it is waiting for input. I did not see a new terminal launched. Maybe I am mistaken something here?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I missed the closing quotation mark.  `xterm -e 'ls ~ ; bash -l'`

Comment: @Keith: this is so nice and exactly what I sought.

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

tried this?

```
(cd /some/dir; xterm)
```

The difference: `cd` is a shell command, `ls` is an executable.

Comment: actually, before accepting your answer, how can I do "ls ~" in the newly launched terminal and show the results there?

Comment: I don't really get what you want. To "launch a terminal with a specified directory" (i.e. your question), this is what you need. To launch a specific command there, use `xterm -e ...`. For more options, `man xterm`.